# Logical operations between strings

Tags: php, string

Suppose you have some strings, how should I transform them in order to be able to use logical operations on them in PHP? Is it even possible?

Example: I want

```
"x=1"&&"x=0"
```

to return `false`.

Comment: You'll have to *parse* those strings and run code based on them. How arbitrary can those expressions be? What does `x=0` mean exactly? Assign `0` to `x`? Compare a variable `$x` to `0`?

Comment: @deceze the strings are logical expressions, so `x=0` means that the variable `x` has value `0`

Comment: can you give a more complex example? the current one can be solved with a simple `explode`, but i guess this won't be the case for all of your input.

Comment: @user1301428 Strings are strings and not logical expressions; `x = 0` isn't a logical expressions either, but a variable assignment. ("the strings are logical expressions, so x=0 means that the variable x has value 0" – that are totally different things…) If you wish to use strings as logical expressions, you'll need to use [`eval()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/951373/when-is-eval-evil-in-php). But then again 'x=0' isn't valid PHP-code (missing the dollar-sign in front of the variable name). Maybe you should explain, why are you trying to evaluate strings as expressions.

Comment: ...and if you've missed that distinction, then you're not likely to understand the implications of using eval() and how to make it safe.

Comment: feeela: 'strings are strings' - a php file is just a string too. his strings are just another formal language which can be parsed and evaluated as expressions. and while his example isn't valid php, it is valid python code...

Comment: @feeela I understand what you are saying, let me try to make things clearer: suppose that I have two strings, `"x=true || x=false"` and `"x=true"`. I would like to use the logical operators in PHP to evaluate the logical AND of the two strings, thus giving me the result `true` in this case. I want to do this because I need to store this information as strings, but I also need to perform logical operations on them.

Comment: @l4mpi sure, another example, besides the one given in the comment for feeela, could be `"!(x!=0&&y=1)"` and `"y=0"`. What I would like to do is evaluate the logical expression `!(x!=0&&y=1)&&y=0`

Comment: You'll probably need something like [this math parser (http://www.bestcode.com/html/math_parser_for_php.html)](http://www.bestcode.com/html/math_parser_for_php.html). [here is another one (https://simplemathparser.codeplex.com/)](https://simplemathparser.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Introduction**

I noticed you have both [Logical Operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php) `&&` and [Assignment Operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php) in a string `=` and you want to evaluate the assignment has a logical operator in a string.  Seriously i don't know how you got here but this is `very wrong` but for education purpose tag along

**Breakdown**

```
"x=1"  &&  "x=0" = False 
  ^    ^     ^
  |    |     | 
       |     |
X == 1 |     |
       |     |
      AND    |
             |
           X == 0
```

The above expression would always be `false` because `X` can not be `equal` to `0` and `1` at the same time

To be able to have such evaluation in `PHP` you need to write your own function eg `logicalString`  where you can evaluate the expression with something like `logicalString("x=1")` or `logicalString("x=0")`

**Assumption**

```
$x = 1; // Imagine value of X
```

**Example 1 &&**

```
// Start Evaluation with &&
if (logicalString("x=1") && logicalString("x=0")) {
    echo "&& - True\n";
} else {
    echo "&& - False\n";
}
```

**Output 1**

```
&& - False
```

**Example 2 - ||**

```
// Start Evaluation with ||
if (logicalString("x=1") || logicalString("x=0")) {
    echo "|| - True\n";
} else {
    echo "|| - False\n";
}
```

**Output 2**

```
|| - True
```

Function Used ( *[Not to be used in production See Why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557787/are-global-variables-in-php-considered-bad-practice-if-so-why)* )

```
function logicalString($str) {
    parse_str($str, $v);
    foreach ( $v as $k => $var ) {
        if (! isset($GLOBALS[$k]) || $GLOBALS[$k] != $var)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

[SEE ONLINE DEMO on PHP 4.3.0 - 5.5.0alpha3](http://3v4l.org/Jm1uR)

Answer (score 2):

With the given information and let me explain what's happening ?

```
if("x=1"&&"x=0")
{
  echo "true";
}
else 
{
  echo "false";
}
```

It will output

```
true
```

What you are trying achieve is not vaild. String is not a logical expression, logical expression consists of one or more logical operators and logical, numeric, or relational operands. [Read more](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php)

What above code does is same as below

```
if("string1" && "string2")
{
  echo "true";
}
else 
{
  echo "false";
}
```

Simply it does not care about what's in there. All it cares is there are two string which are not empty.

```
if("" && "")
{
  echo "true";
}
else 
{
  echo "false";
}
```

above will return `false`.

***Conclusion***

String is a always a string not a logical operator.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way to accomplish your task is to use a custom function trough [eval()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) method like this:

```
<?php
function checkValues($var1, $var2) {
    if ($var1==1 && $var2==1) {
        echo "Both values are equal to 1";
    } else {
        echo "At least one value is not equal to 1";
    }
}

$x = 1;
$y = 1;
$z = 2;
$z3 = 1;

eval("checkValues($x, $y);"); // Both values are equal to 1
eval("checkValues($x, $z);"); // At least one value is not equal to 1

/* The eval parameter is a string so you can play with it.
 * Don't forget the semicolon ";";
 */
eval("checkValues($x, $z" . 3 . ");"); // Both values are equal to 1
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
//Returns True if strings are equal, false otherwise
(bool)!strcmp($str1, $str2);
```

Wrap that in a function and you're set.